# NSTextField over NSOpenGLView

Tags: cocoa, opengl, nsopenglview

I have made a window with an NSOpenGLView that I am rendering openGL content into.

I want to add some buttons and text fields to the view: I can add NSTextFields and NSButtons using interface builder (or code) but they do not appear.

NSOpenGLView is documented as not being able to have sub views, so I then made my own CustomGLView by deriving directly from NSView and implementing the code to create and use a NSOpenGLContext in it. But the subviews are still not appearing :- the OpenGL context paints over them.

On Windows this problem does not exist:- Windows used to host OpenGL MUST have the `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` and `WS_CHIPSIBLINGS` styles set ensuring that any peer, or sub children (views) will not be obscured by the OpenGL surface.

How do I get subviews to display over a NSView thats drawing using OpenGL ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have 2 choices:

1. Create a window just for the text field. Add as a child window of the one hosting the OpenGL view. Major downside is you have to manage positioning it correctly if the Open GL view is moved.
2. Set up your view hierarchy like so:

   - Layer-*backed* view

     - Layer-*hosting* view whose layer contains an OpenGL layer
     - Text field

Comment: I don't quite know what is meant by a layer backed view.
http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/LayerBackedOpenGLView/ doesn't imply that much special needs to happen to the hosting view at all. Perhaps its implicit in the buffering selected. All you need to do really is:
`[openGLView setWantsLayer:YES]`

Comment: Totally - Pick #2 and go for `CAOpenGLLayer` and forget about this obsolete, buggy and awkward class called `NSOpenGLView`. It's not worth it (these days).

Answer (score 6):

Simply call `-setWantsLayer:YES` on the subviews of the NSOpenGLView.

Comment: If you do this, then make sure you profile your code. Adding a CA Layer for an NSOpenGLView can result in a massive performance hit. The additional memory and rendering time is proportional to the size of your NSOpenGLView. For my project (a game), the frame rate was more than halved.

Answer (score 1):

[NSOpenGLView](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenGLView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) cannot have subviews according to the documentation. Even if you subclass the NSOpenGLView, that will change nothing.

What you can do is to create a NSView that will hold both the NSOpenGLView and the NSTextField. You then overlap them in the right order to make one draw atop the other.

Comment: I didn't subclass the NSOpenGGView - i created an entirely new NSView subclass that I then added code to to get an NSOpenGLContext.

Comment: I tried that in Interface Builder: Created a generic content NSView, and give it a NSOpenGLView and a NSButton. It doesn't matter which way around I position them, the NSOpenGLView always paints over the NSButton / NSTextField.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not heavily into OpenGL yet, but it's my understanding that you can accomplish the visual *effect* of subviews with Quartz Extreme using layer-backed views; however, those may be [problematic](http://lists.apple.com/archives/mac-opengl/2009/Mar/msg00081.html). Since subviews are not supported directly, any solution is liable to be a hack.

Indeed, the solution in that link actually hacks a second window to appear over your OpenGL display, the second window displaying the Cocoa views you desire.

The following code (from the above link) is something I've not tested (again not being an OpenGL guy by nature -- yet), but appears like a fairly clever approach:

```
// This is the GL Window and view you already have
glWindow = [[GLWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:windowRect];
glView = [[[GLView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, windowRect.size.width, windowRect.size.height)] autorelease];
[glView translateOriginToPoint:NSMakePoint(glView.bounds.size.width/2, glView.bounds.size.height/2)];
[glWindow setContentView:glView];

// And here's your transparent UI window
uiWindow = [[TransparentWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:windowRect];
uiView = [[[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, windowRect.size.width, windowRect.size.height)] autorelease];
[uiView translateOriginToPoint:NSMakePoint(uiView.bounds.size.width/2, uiView.bounds.size.height/2)];
uiView.wantsLayer = YES;

[uiWindow setContentView:uiView];
[glWindow addChildWindow:uiWindow ordered:NSWindowAbove];
```

Again, I've not tested this, but it looks like it will get you the visual effect you desire.

Comment: Please see my comment below about the performance impact of using a layer this way.

Answer (score 1):

The text can be rendered into a texture -- I just used this for a project, did a lot of looking for sample code, and ultimately found Apple's GLString demo code, which was an absolute trove of how-to:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CocoaGL/Listings/GLString_m.html

I haven't tried adding buttons, but you can, of course, draw your own and comparing the positions of click events with those of your buttons...

Answer (score 1):

This was my solution:

1) Create a parent NSView (let's call it **parentView**).

2) Add an NSOpenGLView Child to **parentView**.

3) Add an additional NSView Child to **parentView** (make sure this is after the OpenGLView within the hierarchy). You can add additional TextFields, etc. to this view.

4) In the ViewController for the parent make sure you call [parentView setWantsLayer: TRUE];  I did this within **-(void) viewWillAppear**

Answer (score 1):

1) The NSOpenGLView **can** have a subview. It can have plenty even.

2) The reason **some** views, controls and other elements are being bullied by NSOpenGLView is due to the loading process when the Application launches. I.e If you add a slider or textfield **above** and into the content view of the window where the NSOpenGLView also resides, upon Application-Launch that textfield will most likely wind up beneath the NSOpenGLView.

This is an Apple Bug. And they know about it.

You can solve it quite easily even without adding a subview to NSOpenGLView...

In Interface Builder drag i.e. a CustomView into the canvas (Not the view). And set it the way you want it with sliders, text and what not. Then create an outlet (Call it i.e topView) in your view controller. Then somewhere in your code... Perhaps (applicationDidFinishLaunching) add this line...

[_window.contentView addSubview:_topView];
(Do your positioning & layout)
This will do the exact same thing as if you had dragged it into the contentView yourself inside IB. Only it will draw the darn thing in the correct Z position.

You loose IB's constraints this way and have to it manually

One could also just subclass and CAOpenGLLayer and use that as a backing layer inside of a regular NSView. There too it is drawn correctly...

Here is Apple's way of wanting to do that. CALayers are a Godsend ;)

Enter following String ** NSOpenGLLayer** in search and hit enter to get to where it is...
[NSOpenGLLayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/index.html)

Hope this helps....